# Apache2 subdomain serve up the same conent

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I'm a programmer whos been thrown into the sys admin world and have a quick question.

I have a web server that I'm trying to add a mobile subdomin for (i.e. m.server.com).

Currently the config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.com
  ServerAlias www.server.com

  DocumentRoot /home/fc/app/current/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName server.com
  ServerAlias www.server.com

  DocumentRoot /home/fc/app/current/public

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I'm thinking that adding a `m` subdomain that goes to the same place should be easy, right?  Would this work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.com
  ServerAlias www.server.com, m.server.com

  DocumentRoot /home/fc/app/current/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost correct, but you don't need the comma between entries in a ServerAlias directive:

`ServerAlias www.server.com m.server.com`

Comment: Will this redirect the `m.server.com` to http://server.com?  Currently all the `www` requests are redirected.  I wouldn't want the `m` subdomain to be cut off.

Comment: nothing shown in your post redirects anything, it just matches and servers files accordingly. There are various things that could redirect your page... rewrite rules in you httpd.conf or in a .htaccess, maybe just a "UseCanonicalName on" or even in the application (CMS, Blog, etc... ) that actually provides your content...

Answer (score 1):

That would work if you remove the `,`. If you don't have any more vhosts, than this two, it would even work without adding `m.server.com`